# How to style React Bootstrap Table column filter box

Tags: react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have a react-bootstrap-table with column filters. I need the filter boxes to appear at the bottom of the column title

I have tried adding style: `{display:block}` to each filtering columns but it does not work

```
function App() {
    const columns = [{
          dataField: 'id',
          text: 'Product ID',
        }, {
          dataField: 'name',
          text: 'Product Name',
          filter: textFilter({style:{display:'block'}})
        }, {
          dataField: 'price',
          text: 'Product Price',
          filter: textFilter({style:{display:'block'}})
        }];
    const [apps, setApps] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <Router basename="/resources/apps">
      <div className="App">

      <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ apps } columns={ columns } filter={ filterFactory() } />

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I expected it to show the column filter boxes to show below the column titles. But the boxes are appearing next to each column titles

Answer (score 3):

It is not a perfect solution and I would prefer some styling at the component level, but this worked for me.

If you add this bit of css to your project (the where depends on your project, but mine is CRA based and I just added it to the index.css file)

```css
.react-bootstrap-table>table>thead>tr>th .filter-label {
  width: 100%
}
```

My text filters went from being on the same line as the column title sitting on a new line.

Alternately (and probably the better choice), use the approach outlined here: [Header Formatter](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Header%20Columns&selectedStory=Column%20Format%20with%20Filter%20and%20Sort&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

For example, you can create a formatter that looks like this:

```
const headerFormatter = (column, colIndex, { sortElement, filterElement }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <span>
        {column.text} {sortElement}
      </span>
      {filterElement}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And then associate that custom formatter with the columns you wish to use it on.